# What does LHSOR mean in this question?

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

What does LHSOR mean in this question?

Comment: No idea, unfortunately.

Comment: No guess as to the acronym, but the recursion is easy to solve (it's just the Fibonacci numbers).

Comment: @lulu I wouldn't say "easy to solve". Saying it's the fibonacci numbers is just giving it a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would interpret the acronym as Linear Homogeneous Second Order Recurrence.